How is the area under the power curve related to acceleration?
How is the area under the power curve, given by its integral, related to an object's acceleration? The bigger the area, the higher the acceleration?
But a bigger area (bigger RPM window) starts to operate at a lower power, which is not good. Isn't the goal to operate at maximum power (narrow RPM window - small area) all the time?


I wonder why you are using such a non-linear power scale. It gives the false impression that up to about 5000 rpm the engine (if that's what we're dealing with) is giving a constant torque, $G$, (since power = $G\omega$, in which $\omega$ is the angular velocity, proportional to the rpm).

@PhilipWood because that is how looks curve of ICE engine

Power is the rate of doing work:
$$P = \frac{\mathrm{d}W}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$
Work is force times distance:
$$W = Fx$$
so at constant RPM,
$$P = \frac{\mathrm{d}(Fx)}{\mathrm{d}t} = F\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} =  Fv$$
and finally, since $F=ma$,
$$P = mav.$$
Your plot is basically a spectral response of the engine:
$$P(f)$$
where $f$ is the frequency in RPM. The area under that isn't really a useful measure of anything.
Now, if you don't have any gears, then RPM and velocity are proportional:
$$f= \alpha v$$
so now you can go back to
$$P(f) = mav$$
and get
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{P(\alpha v)}{mv} $$
from which you can solve for $v(t)$... in theory.

so flatter power curve  gives higher accelaration?

no, higher power curve gives higher acceleration, but it falls at lower velocity. If you want to know what the shape of the curve does, you have to solve the differential equation, which is something you have to do numerically.

if greatest force is at max torque, why we dont drive car in max torque rpm band instead max power rpm band? max force gives max acceleration... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZBqb0ZJSwU
